# equivalent definition of reduced group $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

If $G$ is a discrete group,the reduced $C^*$ algebra of  $G$ is the completion of $\mathbb{C}[G]$ with respect to the norm $||x||_{r}=||\lambda(x)||_{\mathbb{B}(l^2(G))}$,where $\lambda$ is the left regular representation of $\mathbb{C}[G]$.
There is another definition, the reduced $C^*$ algebra of  $G$ is the closure of $\lambda(\mathbb{C}[G])$ with respect to $||||$$_{\mathbb{B}(l^2(G))}$.How to show these two definitions are equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

The mapping $\lambda:(\mathbb C[G],\|\cdot\|_r)\to(\mathbb B(\ell^2(G)),\|\cdot\|_{\mathbb B(\ell^2(G))})$ is an isometry into a complete metric space, hence extends to an isometry on the completion of $(\mathbb C[G],\|\cdot\|_r)$.

Comment: Does this mean $\overline{\mathbb{C}[G]}^{||.||_{r}}=\overline{\lambda(\mathbb{C}[G])}^{||.||_{\mathbb{B}(l^2(G))}}$                     I am a little confused!

Comment: They are the same up to isometric $*$-isomorphism.

Comment: @Aweygan,  $\lambda$ extends to an isometry $\bar{\lambda}$ on the completion$(\mathbb C[G],\|\cdot\|_r)$. I know that an isometry $\bar{\lambda}$ is injective, but how to check it is also surjective?

Comment: @mathbeginner Because it contains a dense subset in its range (namely $\mathbb CG$), and the image of a $C^*$-algebra under a $*$-homomorphism is always closed.

Comment: You mean $\bar{\lambda}(\overline{\mathbb{C}[G]}^{||.||_{r}})=\overline{\lambda(\mathbb{C}[G])}^{||.||_{\mathbb{B}(l^2(G))}}$?

Comment: Yes. $\ \ \ \ $